# compare two fields data from database

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates

models.py

```
class ReportType(models.Model):
    report = models.ForeignKey(Report)
    title = models.CharField('Incident Type', max_length=200)

class Report(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=False)
    app_uuid = models.CharField('Unique App Id', max_length=100)

class Types(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True)
    title = models.CharField('Incident Type', max_length=200)
    is_active = models.BooleanField('Is Active', default=True)
```

In Types table,i am saving some default data in title field.The data entered by user are saved in ReportType table.

I want to compare the data in title field in Types model and ReportType model.After comparison,if title field data in ReportType model is not present in Types model,i need to display that in template.I need to show the non matching value present in ReportType model.

template.html

```
{% for type in report_type %} 
 {{type.title}}{% endfor %}
```

I tried with this query

```
 report_type = Report.objects.filter(reporttype__title=F('types__title'))
```

I am getting this error `"Cannot resolve keyword 'types' into field"`,this is because Types table don't have relation with Report table.Need help.

Comment: To me it looks like you should re-think your models. `Report` should probably have a FK to `ReportType` and not the other way around. Please add some more info on what it is you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @dan-klasson,i am trying to achieve the mismatched item from Types table.Types table have some default values stores,meanwhile data entered by user gets saved in ReportType table,i want to check if the entered data by user is not available in Types table,if not their i need to display that mismatched item in template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you need at least 2 queries then:

```
# get all types as a list
all_types = Types.objects.values_list('title', flat=True)

# you need to show the mismatch, then use exclude()
report_type = ReportType.objects.exclude(title__in=all_types)
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: How to compare the two models title field,if their is mismatch in two title field data,need to show in template.How to query the two table's data and compare.

Comment: Check my edited answer then, you need to use `exclude()` instead of `filter()` since you want to get the list of mismatch only

Comment: I confused,i used exclude in Report object.I want to select the title from ReportType model and Types model and compare both.If their is mismatch need to show the mismatched one.I printed the report_type in console,it printed  Report object.If their is any mismatch in both models title field it is not showing in template.I updated my template in question.

Comment: Ah your question wasn't clear, I thought you had to get the report with mismatched report type. Answer updated.

Answer (score 0):

You can filter ReportType objects and get Reports from result queryset like this:

```
ReportType.objects.values_list('report').filter(title__in=Types.objects.values_list('title', flat=True).distinct())
```